# return isEven(-number ); Eloquent javascript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, eloquent

I am going through the exercises from http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html and am having difficulty understanding a specific part of the recursion exercise. The exercise asks to print true or false based on a value entered as a parameter.

After attempting this exercise I realised I had used the wrong technique and after looking at the solution I was confused about how the second else if statement works which checks if parameter entered is a minus value.

`function isEven(number){
    if (number == 0){
        return true;
    } else if (number == 1){
        return false;
    } else if (number < 0){
        return isEven(-number );
    } else {
        return isEven(number -2);
    }
}
console.log(isEven(-2)); // true
console.log(isEven(-5)); // false`

I'm confused as to how the negative value being subtracting from itself eg `return isEven(-number )`, provides a `true` or `false` value. eg `-5 -(-5) = 0` so this will return `true` but `-5` is not an even value, it is odd.

Could I get an explanation as to how this recursive code works with a minus parameter please?

Comment: console.log(number)

Comment: `-number` means **multiply by -1**. Why do you think it's **subtracting from itself**?

Comment: Good Grief! This is, without a doubt, the absolute ***worst*** example of recursion I have ever seen. I would not trust the eloquent JS book from that alone since it's apparent the author is way too lazy to even come up with decent examples.

Comment: @paxdiablo: What don't you like about it?

Comment: @squint determine whether even or odd shouldn't be so complicated. Isn't `number % 2` enough?

Comment: @Leo: It's an example for teaching recursion. `number % 2` wouldn't do it.

Comment: @squint, recursive solutions provide an eloquent way to do problems in terms of similar, smaller problems and their power lies in their ability to reduce the answer space quickly (such as binary search which reduces it by half each time). Try that function in the question with `isEven(1e38)` and you'll see just how bad it is - you'll either blow up your stack or still be waiting for an answer long after the heat death of the universe :-) Hyperbole, obviously, but you should get the idea.

Comment: @squint Programming is like thinking. Does anyone use recursion to find the answer in real life? It's obviously not a proper use case. I think that's why @ paxdiablo thinks it's terrible. And I agree with it. My personal favorite book for entry level is _PPK on JavaScript_, however it's a bit outdated.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yeah it's definitely the kind of code you'd want to see in the real world. I think it's just meant to be an exercise to get a person to think about covering necessary escape clauses.

Comment: @Leo: it's not presented as a proper use case, just an exercise. These are pretty common. Another take on this example is using indirect recursion to get the same result by utilizing an `isEven` and an `isOdd` function. The exercises are silly yet are small and simple enough for a beginner to wrap their head around.

Comment: @paxdiablo It's not just a stack problem, or that it would require too much time. The problem is that `1e38 - 2 === 1e38`, so the loop would theoretically never end, even if having an infinite stack and infinite time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative sign converts a negative number to a positive one, so that the second recursive case can continue to subtract by 2 until it reaches one of the base cases (0 or 1), which then tells you if it's even or odd :)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a slight misunderstanding about what `-number` does. This is not subtracting the number from itself, but rather producing the negative *of the number*, e.g. `-5` => `5`, or `2` => `-2`.

I will say, this code has a lot of ways it could be cleaned up -- the first and most important of which is that it's immensely easier to test for evenness or oddness by using the modulo operator (`%`), which returns the remainder of dividing a number by another number. In this case, all odd integers modulo'd by 2 will return 1, and all even numbers will return 0. This would be, in nearly every way, a better way to go about this than recursing towards 0. A general rule of thumb -- if you're recursing in a high-level language in order to perform basic arithmetic, there's probably a simpler solution.

Comment: I initially used modulus and was able to get the result I wanted very quickly and easily, however this activity asked to use recursive techniques.
From using console.log(number) before the if statement i was able to see that the -6 value is updated with each recursion to positive values and then number goes through the final else statement 
I think a better way is to us Math.abs(value) or doing this (-6 X -1 = 6). 
After a bit of research I discovered that using the - operator before a negative value creates a positive value eg - (-6)= 6.  
Thanks for the feedback peeps.